# VB.NET Extract file paths from string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm not so good with regular expressions and I need help with following task:

In VB.NET, I need to extract one or more FILE paths from randomly given string - exactly process command line arguments. For example:

I need from this:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" /n` `"C:\Users\administrator\Documents\test.docx" /o ""`

extract array of this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE

C:\Users\administrator\Documents\test.docx
```

Tried to search here but did not helped me. Thanks for help!

EDIT: Based on response, I created this code. But it extracts only the first path, not the second:

EDIT 2: Based on second response (marked as correct) I edited my code and its working now!

```
´Public Function GetProcessOpenedFiles(ByVal p As Process) As List(Of String)
    Dim newlst As New List(Of String)

    Dim strCmdArgs As String = GetProcessCommandLine(p)
    Dim strExePath As String = GetProcessExePath(p).ToLower

    Dim expression As String = """(.+?)"""
    Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(strCmdArgs, expression)

    For Each m As Match In mc
        Dim strMatch As String = m.ToString.ToLower
        strMatch = Mid(strMatch, 2)
        strMatch = strMatch.Remove(strMatch.Length - 1)

        If strExePath <> strMatch Then
            If IO.File.Exists(strMatch) AndAlso newlst.Contains(strMatch) = False Then
                newlst.Add(strMatch)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return newlst
End Function´
```

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: Did you try System.IO.Path functions? Very helpful for pulling path info. It doesn't even have to be file paths. You can use it for URLs etc.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I know IO.Path class, but it does not (AFAIK) contain any feature which can retrieve list of string (paths) from randomly given text.

Also, the best regex here is working on paths encapsulated in "" symbol, if it's without encapsulation, function fails and does not retrieve paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
"(.+?)"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/dF3mB4/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-61]  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE`
MATCH 2
1.  [67-109]    `C:\Users\administrator\Documents\test.docx`
```

Comment: Yes, this regex is better than previous one - worked fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Grab everything from the opening `"` to the next `"` characters.

```
^"([^"]+)"
```

and you're done.

Comment: It does not work exactly as I mentioned, see edited question please.